# How to add a lap timer in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0

I've got a 2D racing game that I'm developing. Here's a screenshot of the game in XNA;http://oi41.tinypic.com/vxhy5y.jpg . I want to know how to create a lap timer. So for instance, "if car1blue/car2red collides with chequered flag start timer, and if they collide a second time, stop timer." Will this work in theory? If it does work in theory, how do I do it in XNA?

If you want, I could provide the code I've done so far.

Thank you very much!

EDIT;
Is it possible if you could show me what code goes where?

Comment: I think you need to change your question, the current question is how do you find out how long a lap took, but from the code above you are missing a game implementation... If you are wanting to know how to put together a racing game then you will need to break your problem down into: 1) How do I draw a car to the screen 2) How do I move a car on the screen 3) How do I calculate collisions on a moving object. Once you have the answers to those 3 questions you can use the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you have put it all together, can you not just store a DateTime somewhere of the time they passed the line, so when it starts you do:

```
public MyGame
{
    DateTime lastLapTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan lastLapTime = new TimeSpan();
    // other stuff

    public void Update(TimeSpan elapsedTime)
    {
        if(HasCompletedLap)
        {
            var currentLapTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
            lastLapTime = currentLapTimestamp - lastLapTimestamp;
            lastLapTimestamp = currentLaptimeStamp;
        }
        // Other stuff
    }
}
```

Then just display your lastLapTime wherever you want to see how long it took to go around.

Comment: Look, I'm a complete newbie to XNA, you're confusing me even more here :( .

Comment: Not really, I dont know your collision detection system, I dont know how your update methods are called, I dont have a clue about ANY of your implementation. So the only way I can help is by giving you some near implementation-like psudocode. Ultimately the bit you need to do is take a snapshot of the time when you pass the line (or start the race) and then every subsequent time check the new timestamp, then work out the time that has passed... I know everyone has to start somewhere but you sound like you are running before you can walk.If you provide us with more information maybe we can help

Answer (score 0):

As requested here is the implementation that would be required in your example empty XNA project, again I am ONLY answering the question you pose above about the lap time:

```
/* 
    NEW MEMBERS FOR YOU TO IMAGINE YOU HAVE SOME MEANINGFUL RACING GAME 
*/
private Vector2 yourPosition;
private Texture2D yourCar;
private Texture2D yourTrack;
private Rectangle yourStartingLine;

private DateTime currentLapTimestamp = DateTime.Now();
private TimeSpan currentLapTime = new TimeSpan();

public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}

protected override void Initialize()
{
    // Put your starting line somewhere
    yourStartingLine = new Rectangle(100,100,10,100)

    base.Initialize();  
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    yourCar = Content.Load<Texture2D>("YourCarAssetName")
    yourTrack = Content.Load<Texture2D>("YourTrackAssetName")
}

protected override void UnloadContent()
{
    // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Check your keyboard input
    UpdatePosition(Keyboard.GetState());
    if(HasPassedStartingLine())
    { UpdateLapTime(); }
    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    DrawTrack();
    DrawCar();
    DrawLapTime();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}

/* 
    NEW METHODS FOR YOU TO PRETEND DO STUFF
*/  

private void UpdateLapTime()
{
    var newTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
    currentLapTime = newTimestamp - currentLapTimestamp;
}

private bool HasPassedStartingLine()
{
    // Work out if you have passed the starting line
    // and make sure you dont register it again until
    // they have passed the finish line
}

private void UpdatePosition(KeyboardState keyboardState)
{
    // Assumes you work out how to handle your players
    // controls to move the position of the car
}

private void DrawTrack()
{
    // Your rendering logic for the track
}

private void DrawCar()
{
    // Your rendering logic for the car
}

private void DrawLapTime()
{
    // your rendering logic for the lap time
}
```